# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) — как узнать — на какой строке ошибка (PHP)?

Tags: php, отладка

Сервер возвращает ошибку:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

Как узнать, на какой строке она произошла? У меня Netbeans. Я создаю точку останова в начале функции, а потом просто жму F7 (войти). Но это оочень долго, особенно, если функция большая. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно проще и быстрее узнать, на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: откройте логи web-сервера и посмотрите, где, во сколько, в каком файле и на какой строчке произошла ошибка.

Comment: @And, я использую OpenServer. Я открыл логи. Произвел действия, которые вызывают данную ошибку. Но в логах ничего не обновилось. Может, я что-то не так делаю?
Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый. Я новичок и никогда раньше не читал логи.

Comment: Видимо не так что-то с директивами. `.htaccess`, может где-то нарушили, что-то? Может помочь если к примеру за комментировать директивы `Options`, может быть много нюансов данной ошибки..

Comment: `Но это оочень долго, особенно, если функция большая` - а вы думали это за 5 секунд делается? Некоторые могут и по пол дня отлаживать код.

Comment: в php пропишите как-то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482  ...... и попробуйте еще раз логи

Comment: Смотрите файлы, где последний раз, что-то изменяли, смотрите тщательно, где нарушен синтаксис в php.